# Uninstall springsource tools suite

Tags: sts-springsourcetoolsuite

I have installed a springsource tools suite 2.5 and I want to move to 2.6 version, so I was looking for uninstalling the older version, but i don't find the uninstaller.
So, deleting the directory in which the older version is installed is sufficient or are there other procedures to do?

Answer (score 4):

No, it's just a big directory structure, you can delete it without side effects.

Answer (score 3):

For uninstall STS

1. open STS
2. Go to Help -> About Spring Tool Suite
3. Click on installation details
4. Check installed software
5. Click on Spring tool suite under installed software
6. Click Uninstall.

That's it.

Answer (score 1):

Under Windows XP that is not true.

There are folders ".grails" and ".groovy" under "C:\Documents and Settings" that need to be deleted.

Something locks the installation folder that let not you fully remove it. F